# Re-rending Propblem in React when trying to filter the data using useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

This is App.js. I am trying to change the HouseDetails with `useState` Hook, whenever I tried its showing re-rendring problem.

```
import "./App.css";
import Card from "./components/Card";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import { HiChevronDown } from "react-icons/hi";
import { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import HouseDetails from "./components/RealState/HouseDetails";

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(HouseDetails);
  // const [items, setItems] = useState(HouseDetails);
  
  
  const filterHouse = (e) => {

    const newHouse = e.filter((f) => {
      f.name.includes('Collsmith'); return 1;
    })

    // dont call setItems inside useMemo
    // it triggers another render 
    // which triggers another useMemo call
    // setItems(newHouse);
    
  }
  
  
  const updatedItems = useMemo(() => filterHouse(items), [items]);
  setItems(updatedItems);

  return (
    <div className="w-full justify-center">
      <Header />
      <main className="w-[76%] m-auto">
        <div className="my-14 py-2">
          <div className="sm:flex justify-between items-center">
            <ul>
              <li className="hidden sm:block lg:text-4xl font-semibold">
                Search properties to rent
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul className="flex items-center justify-between border-2 border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-gray-600">
              <li className="font-semibold">
                <input
                  type="search"
                  className="outline-none"
                  placeholder="Search with Search Bar"
                />
              </li>
              <li>
                <HiChevronDown />
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <NavBar />
        </div>

        {/* main-content */}

        <div className="grid xl:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-row-3 md:grid-cols-2 lg:gap-8 md:gap-6 sm:gap-4">
          <Card items={items} />
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is Card.js

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import { FiHeart } from "react-icons/fi";
import { MdBed } from "react-icons/md";
import { BiBath, BiArea } from "react-icons/bi";

const Card = ({ items }) => {

  return items && items.map((elem) => {
    const { id, image, name, location, price, beds, bathrooms, area } = elem;
    return (
      <article key={id} className="flex-col justify-center rounded-lg shadow-md max-w-xl">
        <div className="rounded-lg">
          <img src={require('./house1.jpg')} alt="" className="rounded-lg h-72 w-full" />
        </div>
        <div className="flex-col justify-center px-4 py-2 space-y-3">
          <div className="flex-col justify-center space-y-1">
            <ul className="flex justify-between items-center">
              <li className="text-purple-600 font-bold text-2xl">
                ${price}
                <span className="text-sm text-gray-400 font-semibold">
                  /month
                </span>
              </li>
              <li className="cursor-pointer p-2 rounded-full border-2 border-gray-300 text-xl text-purple-600">
                <FiHeart />
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li className="font-bold text-gray-600 text-2xl">{name}</li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li className="text-gray-400 text-sm">{location}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-between items-center py-3">
            <ul className="flex justify-between items-center">
              <li className="text-xl pr-2 text-purple-600">
                <MdBed />
              </li>
              <li className="text-xs text-gray-400 font-semibold">
                {beds} Beds
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul className="flex justify-between items-center">
              <li className="text-xl pr-2 text-purple-600">
                <BiBath />
              </li>
              <li className="text-xs text-gray-400 font-semibold">
                {bathrooms} Bathrooms
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul className="flex justify-between items-center">
              <li className="text-xl pr-2 text-purple-600">
                <BiArea />
              </li>
              <li className="text-xs text-gray-400 font-semibold">
                {area} m2
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    );
  });
};

export default Card;
```

Still showing error, re-rendoring.

Comment: To solve this error you should use useCallback hook rather than useMemo because useMemo will call the function every time.

Comment: I think you are passing your filterhouse function in child comp & you don't want allow to re render the child comp unwantedly when items changes, then useCallback hook is a good solution.

Comment: You are making `setItems(newHouse);` inside `useMemo()` that causes that each render will trigger `useMemo()`again (`items` being changed).
try just to return `newHouse` from `filterHouse()`

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix comment  `setItems(newHouse);` inside filterHouse

```
 const [items, setItems] = useState(HouseDetails);


  const filterHouse = () => {

    const newHouse = items.filter((item) => {
      return item.name.includes('Collsmith')
    })
    return newHouse

    // dont call setItems inside useMemo
    // it triggers another render 
    // which triggers another useMemo call
    // setItems(newHouse);

  }


  const updatedItems = useMemo(() => filterHouse(items), [items]);
  // do you want to filter based on text
  //const updatedItems = useMemo(() => filterHouse(items, filterString), [items, filterString]);
```

I think you dont want to update HouseDetails after filtering because when you do filtering again, some of the initial items will be removed, which will give you wrong results

and [string.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#specifications) is case sensitive